# Open node debugging url in google-chrome automatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, google-chrome

I would like to open the URL from running the `node --inspect app.js` in the browser automatically. I am on `Ubuntu Linux` and the `osascript` solution does not work well for me.

I have tried:

```
$(grep 'chrome-devtools://' <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1)) | xargs google-chrome

( export DEBUG_URL = $(grep 'chrome-devtools://' <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1)); google-chrome DEBUG_URL )

google-chrome $(grep 'chrome-devtools://' <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1))  

xdg-open $(grep 'chrome-devtools://' <(node --inspect bin/www.js $@ 2>&1))
```

Comment: Any solution yet?